# What does ->std::ostream& mean?

Tags: c++

Here is the part of codes that i cannot understand.This is a func definition.

```
using sPtr = std::shared_ptr < std::vector<int> >;
auto print(sPtr vec) ->std::ostream&;
```

what does it mean by -> std::ostream& ? Is it necessary or not ? In my opinion,

```
void print (sPtr vec) ;
```

I am learning CPP5 ch12 now, and the code is from github Mooophy/Cpp-Primer;
Thanks everyone's advice.

Comment: @EdHeal: that's not a lambda, that's a normal function with a trailing return type.

Comment: I realized that after pressing return - sorryt

Comment: I have never heard of "CPP5 ch12" and have no idea what that means, but you should probably learn C++ with recommended textbooks, not with github repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print` is a function taking a `sPtr` as an input and returning an `std::ostream&`. The syntax being used was introduced in C++11, and it's called ["trailing return type"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction).

The declaration of `print` can be rewritten as follows:

```
std::ostream& print(sPtr vec);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your link.